# Adding tools.jar conditionally

Tags: java, maven, java-11, tools.jar

Currently I have included tools.jar in my pom dependencies. In JDK11 it needs to be removed from dependencies. Please help me including tools.jar in dependencies only if java version is less than 9 else it should be present in pom.

Comment: Are you possibly looking out for [Maven toolchains: sample linked](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html)? Or maybe profiles?

Comment: ...and can you actually detail out the reason why would you need the *tools.jar* in your dependency?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Maven profiles (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java8</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.8</jdk>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>  
           ...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```